# How to insert data row using Entity Framework with Auto Increment column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table name `Product`

It have two columns `ProductID` (primary key and auto incremented(1,1) and `ProductName`.

my product Model :

```
public partial class Product
{
  public int ProductID {get; set;}
  public string ProductName {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to insert the row in the database using entity as :

```
    using(var db = new DbContext()){
    
        Product row = new Product ()
                            {
                             ProductName = "product1"
                            };
                            db.Products.Add(row);
                            db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

but it store id as 0 and not the auto incremented value decided by SQL Sever

Comment: the value of the id will be changed after ```db.SaveChanges();```, also in order to create new object you need to do it like this ```new Product() {ProductName = "product1"}```

Comment: This is Database First model so my database is already computing the productIds

Comment: Could you post the product model? It should match the table and it’s column names. Or otherwise it must be configured to match.

Comment: @BuildItBusk okay done

Comment: How do you verify that it is stored as `0` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this decorator

```
public partial class Product
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [Key]
  public int ProductID {get; set;}
  public string ProductName {get; set;}
}
```

greetings,

Mike